# Best practices for integrating validations in service/controller layer

Tags: spring, validation, service, controller

I use JPA/Spring jpa/data/mvc/validation and I have this class structure:
Pojo/`@Entity`:

```
@MappedSuperclass @public class Base {//} 
@Entity public class Account extends Base {//}
```

JpaRepository interfaces:

```
@NoRepositoryBean public interface BaseRepository<T extends Base> extends JpaRepository<T, Integer> {}
public interface AccountRepository extends BaseRepository<Account> {}
```

I have created validation classes (Spring Validator) for validations which will be used by `@Service`, `@Controller`/`@RestController` classes.
I don't like add any validation `(@Max`, `@Min`, `@NotNull`) in pojo class!

```
public abstract class BaseValidator<T extends Base> implements Validator {}
    @Component public class ConfigValidator extends BaseValidator<Config> {
    public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {     // basic (fields or multifields) validations 
        super.validate(obj, errors);
        //other.validations.
    }   
    public void addValidate(Account obj, Errors errors) { // business validations when add 
       validate(obj, errors);
       super.addValidate(obj,errors);
       //own add validations.
    }
    public void editValidate(Account obj, Errors errors) { // business validations when update }

    public void delValidate(Account obj, Errors errors) { // business validations when add 
        validate(obj, errors);
        super.delValidate(obj,errors);
        //own delete validations.
    }   
}
```

What is the best way to integrate validation classes with `@Service` and `@Controlle`r/`@RestController`?
Something like that?

`@Service`(service Layer): (wrapper repositories + validations)

```
    public abstract class BaseService<T extends Base>{ // }

    @Service public class AccountService extends BaseService<Account> {

        @Autowired AccountRepository repository;
        @Autowired AccountValidator validator;

        add(Account obj, Errors errors) {
            // validator.validate(obj, errors)
            // if (!errors.hasErrors())
            // validator.add(obj, errors)
            // if (!errors.hasErrors())
                repository.add(obj)}
        }

        edit(Account ob, Errors errors) { // } 

        del(Integer id, Errors errors) {
            Account obj = repository.findOne(id);
            // validator.validate(obj, errors)
            // if (!errors.hasErrors())
            // validator.delValidate(obj, errors)
            // if (!errors.hasErrors())
                repository.del(id)}
        }

        // Problem: I don't have a class implements Erros internal call add/del methods. BeanPropertyBindingResult?
   }
```

`@Controller`(Control layer):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Account")
public class AccountController {

    @Autowired AccountService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/Add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addForm(Model model) { // }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/Add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addAction(@Validated @ModelAttribute("entity") Account entity, BindingResult result, Model model) {

        //   if (accountService.add(entity, result) had errors)
        //      return to form with errors.
        }
}
```

What is the best way to integrate validation classes with `@Service` and `@Controller`/`@RestController`?

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

Repository:

```
NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T extends Base> extends JpaRepository<T,     Integer> {
    // Common methods
}

public interface AccountRepository extends BaseRepository<Account> {
    // Account methods
}
```

Validator:

```
public interface BaseValidator<T extends Base> extends Validator {
    // Common methods
}

public interface AccountValidator extends BaseValidator<Account>, Validator     {
    // Account methods
}

public abstract class AbsBaseValidator<T extends Base> implements     BaseValidator<T> {
    private BaseRepository<T> repository;
    // Common methods
}

@Component
public class AccountValidatorImpl extends AbsBaseValidator<Account> implements AccountValidator {
    private AccountRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public AccountValidatorImpl(AccountRepository repository) {
        super(repository);
        this.repository = repository;
    }
    // Account methods
}
```

Service:

```
public interface BaseService<T extends Base> {
    // Common methods
}

public interface AccountService extends BaseService<Account> {
    // Account methods
}

public abstract class AbsBaseService<T extends Base> implements BaseService<T> {

    private BaseRepository<T> repository;
    private BaseValidator<T> validator;
    public AbsBaseService(BaseRepository<T> repository, BaseValidator<T> validator) {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.validator = validator;
    }
        // Common methods       
}

@Service
public class AccountServiceImpl extends AbsBaseService<Account> implements AccountService {

    private AccountRepository repository;
    private AccountValidator validator;
    @Autowired
    public AccountServiceImpl(AccountRepository repository, AccountValidator validator) {
        super(repository, validator);
        this.repository = repository;
        this.validator = validator;
    }
        // Account methods
}
```

Controller:

```
public interface BaseController<T extends Base> {
        // Common methods
}

public interface AccountController extends BaseController<Account> {
    // Account methods
}

public abstract class AbsBaseController<T extends Base> implements BaseController<T> {

    private BaseService<T> service;
    private BaseValidator<T> validator;

    public AbsBaseController(BaseService<T> service, BaseValidator<T> validator) {
        super(service, validator);
        this.service = service;
        this.validator = validator;
        this.obj = service.getInstance();
    }
        // Common methods
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Account")
public class AccountControllerImpl extends AbsBaseController<Account> implements AccountController {

    private AccountService service;
    private AccountValidator validator;

    @Autowired
    public AccountControllerImpl(AccountService service, AccountValidator validator) {
        super(service, validator);
        this.service = service;
        this.validator = validator;
    }
    // Account methods
}
```